# LAG and the first NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, lead

I have the below table:

```
id    date       cust
1     3/13/2019  
1     3/14/2019  Johnson
1     3/19/2019
```

I want to create a column that captures the last cust entry and partition by id.

I have the below..

```
select *
,case
 when a.cust is not null then a.cust
 else lag(a.cust) over partition by a.id order by a.date)
 end lst_cust
from A
```

Results:

```
id  date        cust
 1   3/13/2019
 1   3/14/2019  Johnson
 1   3/19/2019  Johnson
```

How do I capture "Johnson" for row one?

I was thinking about using `lead` too but not sure how to embed both in the case expression and if that's what I'm looking for. Or `LAST_VALUE` with nulls first but can't see to get it to work.

Comment: Simple forms of `LEAD()` and `LAG()` will capture values from adjacent rows only. What if you have 5 rows, or 7, or 9 or 99?

Comment: But isn't capturing John for the first entry a logical error if you want the customer of the last business day for every entry? What is it that you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last_value` is a good idea, just add window clause:

```
select id, date_, 
       nvl(cust, last_value(cust) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by date_ 
                 rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)) cust
  from a
  order by id, date_
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed3ae8cfad37e9978d2ec9a7e77c39ca)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want both `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(a.cust, 
                lag(a.cust) over partition by a.id order by a.date),
                lead(a.cust) over partition by a.id order by a.date)
               ) as lst_cust
from A;
```

You may also want an `ignore nulls` in there, if you can have more than one `null` in a row.